# Is this a Standard Brownian Motion?

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

B(t) is a standard Brownian motion
Is $t\in[0,+\infty]$$\rightarrow$$\sqrt{t}B(1) $ a Standard Brownian Motion?

Not very sure how to verify if it is a standard Brownian motion, because I am unsure of what $\sqrt{t}$ does to the process

Comment: Check the covariance function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(\sqrt tB_1)_{t\geq 0}$ is obviously not a Brownian motion. Indeed, $t\mapsto \sqrt tB_1$ is a.s. differentiable on $(0,\infty )$, whereas a Brownian motion is not. Nevertheless, $B_t$ and $\sqrt tB_1$ have the same distribution.